# Convert columns to list

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data in 2 columns (Region and GroupedCateg). Refer the dataframe below. I want to convert it into nested lists. I tried using **group_by and do()** function of dplyr and then convert into list but it didn't work.

```
df <- read.table(header = T,
                 text = '
Region  GroupedCateg
Beja    Alentejo
Evora   Alentejo
Portalegre  Alentejo
Faro    Algarve
Aveiro  Central
"Castelo Branco"    Central
Coimbra Central
Leiria  Central
Santarem    Central
Acores  Islands
Madeira Islands
Lisboa  Lisbon
Setubal Lisbon
Braga   North
Braganca    North
"Viana do Castelo"  North
"Vila Real" North
Porto   Porto
')
```

**Desired Output in lists. Region would be in names. Respective GroupedCateg in nested list**

```
list(
  list(
    name =  "Alentejo",
    categories = list("Beja", "Evora", "Portalegre")
  ),
  list(
    name =  "Algarve",
    categories = list("Faro")
  ),
  list(
    name =  "Central",
    categories = list("Aveiro", "Castelo Branco", "Coimbra", "Leiria", "Santarem" )
  ),
  
  list(
    name =  "North",
    categories = list("Braga", "Braganca", "Viana do Castelo", "Vila Real")
  ),
  list(
    name =  "Lisbon",
    categories = list("Lisboa", "Setubal")
  ),
  list(
    name =  "Islands",
    categories = list("Acores", "Madeira")
  ),
  
  list(
    name =  "Porto",
    categories = list("Porto")
  )
  
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pmap()` in `purrr`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

x <- df %>%
  group_by(GroupedCateg) %>% 
  summarise(Region = list(Region)) %>%
  pmap(~ list(name = .x, categories = as.list(.y)))
```

---

The corresponding `base` R version:

```
y <- apply(aggregate(Region ~ GroupedCateg, df, c),
     1, function(y) list(name = y[[1]], categories = as.list(y[[2]])))
```

---

```
all.equal(x, y)
# [1] TRUE
```

---

***Output***

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$name
[1] "Alentejo"

[[1]]$categories
[[1]]$categories[[1]]
[1] "Beja"

[[1]]$categories[[2]]
[1] "Evora"

[[1]]$categories[[3]]
[1] "Portalegre"



[[2]]
[[2]]$name
[1] "Algarve"

[[2]]$categories
[[2]]$categories[[1]]
[1] "Faro"



[[3]]
[[3]]$name
[1] "Central"

[[3]]$categories
[[3]]$categories[[1]]
[1] "Aveiro"

[[3]]$categories[[2]]
[1] "Castelo Branco"

[[3]]$categories[[3]]
[1] "Coimbra"

[[3]]$categories[[4]]
[1] "Leiria"

[[3]]$categories[[5]]
[1] "Santarem"



[[4]]
[[4]]$name
[1] "Islands"

[[4]]$categories
[[4]]$categories[[1]]
[1] "Acores"

[[4]]$categories[[2]]
[1] "Madeira"



[[5]]
[[5]]$name
[1] "Lisbon"

[[5]]$categories
[[5]]$categories[[1]]
[1] "Lisboa"

[[5]]$categories[[2]]
[1] "Setubal"



[[6]]
[[6]]$name
[1] "North"

[[6]]$categories
[[6]]$categories[[1]]
[1] "Braga"

[[6]]$categories[[2]]
[1] "Braganca"

[[6]]$categories[[3]]
[1] "Viana do Castelo"

[[6]]$categories[[4]]
[1] "Vila Real"



[[7]]
[[7]]$name
[1] "Porto"

[[7]]$categories
[[7]]$categories[[1]]
[1] "Porto"
```

Comment: Well done, I felt like I was battling lists of lists there. Glad you could put me out of my misery ;)

Comment: Thanks Darren, It's quite informative. Is there a reason you added `unique` in the `aggregate`?

Comment: @DanielO I just thought maybe there are duplicated `Region` in each `GroupedCateg`. Now I think `unique()` might be redundant.

Answer (score 2):

Using base *split* on column, then *lapply* to re-format as desired:

```
x <- split(df$Region, df$GroupedCateg)

res <- lapply(names(x), function(i){
  list(name = i,
       categories = as.list(x[[ i ]]))
})
```

Answer (score 1):

In Base-R

```
apply(aggregate(Region~GroupedCateg,df,c),1, function(x) list(name=x[1], category=as.list(x[2]$Region))) 
    
[[1]]
[[1]]$name
[[1]]$name$GroupedCateg
[1] "Alentejo"


[[1]]$category
[[1]]$category[[1]]
[1] "Beja"

[[1]]$category[[2]]
[1] "Evora"

[[1]]$category[[3]]
[1] "Portalegre"



[[2]]
[[2]]$name
[[2]]$name$GroupedCateg
[1] "Algarve"


[[2]]$category
[[2]]$category[[1]]
[1] "Faro"



[[3]]
[[3]]$name
[[3]]$name$GroupedCateg
[1] "Central"


[[3]]$category
[[3]]$category[[1]]
[1] "Aveiro"

[[3]]$category[[2]]
[1] "Castelo Branco"

[[3]]$category[[3]]
[1] "Coimbra"

[[3]]$category[[4]]
[1] "Leiria"

[[3]]$category[[5]]
[1] "Santarem"



[[4]]
[[4]]$name
[[4]]$name$GroupedCateg
[1] "Islands"


[[4]]$category
[[4]]$category[[1]]
[1] "Acores"

[[4]]$category[[2]]
[1] "Madeira"



[[5]]
[[5]]$name
[[5]]$name$GroupedCateg
[1] "Lisbon"


[[5]]$category
[[5]]$category[[1]]
[1] "Lisboa"

[[5]]$category[[2]]
[1] "Setubal"



[[6]]
[[6]]$name
[[6]]$name$GroupedCateg
[1] "North"


[[6]]$category
[[6]]$category[[1]]
[1] "Braga"

[[6]]$category[[2]]
[1] "Braganca"

[[6]]$category[[3]]
[1] "Viana do Castelo"

[[6]]$category[[4]]
[1] "Vila Real"



[[7]]
[[7]]$name
[[7]]$name$GroupedCateg
[1] "Porto"


[[7]]$category
[[7]]$category[[1]]
[1] "Porto"
```

Comment: Thanks. But I need the exact same output as I need to pass it to one of highcharts functions. If not in the same structure, it won't work.